# How to fix bug ghost text in win32 api static

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a calculator in Windows API c++, and first version is work very well, but my new code when press backspace button it will pop_back the input wstring but text in static doesnt change.

This is my code:

```
// ...
std::vector<HWND> buttons;
HWND inputBox;
std::wstring input = L"0", prevInput, answer;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HFONT hFont = DEFAULT_FONT(DEFAULT_SIZE);

        RECT size{};
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &size);

        int width = size.right - size.left, height = size.bottom - size.top;
        Vector2i boardPos = BOARD_POS(height);
        const int spacing = BUTTON_SPACING;
        Vector2i buttonSize = Vector2i(width / 4 - spacing, (height - boardPos.y) / 4 - spacing);

        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_COLUMNS; col++)
            {
                HWND hButton = CreateWindowExW(
                    0L,
                    L"Button",                   // Predefined class; Unicode assumed
                    buttonTexts[row][col].c_str(),                   // Button text
                    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW,  // Styles
                    (spacing + (buttonSize.x + spacing) * col) + boardPos.x,     // X position
                    (spacing + (buttonSize.y + spacing) * row) + boardPos.y,                  // Y position
                    buttonSize.x,                  // Button width
                    buttonSize.y,                  // Button height
                    hWnd,                        // Parent window
                    reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(row * BOARD_COLUMNS + col + 1),    // Button ID
                    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
                    NULL);                       // Pointer not needed
                SendMessage(hButton, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, MAKELPARAM(0, TRUE));

                buttons.push_back(hButton); // Store button handle
            }
        }

        inputBox = CreateWindowEx(0L, L"Static", input.c_str(), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, width, boardPos.y - 0, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        SendMessage(inputBox, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, MAKELPARAM(0, TRUE));

        DeleteObject(hFont);

        break;
    }

    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = reinterpret_cast<LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT>(lParam);

        if (lpdis->CtlID >= 1 && lpdis->CtlID <= buttons.size())
        {
            TEXTMETRIC tm;
            GetTextMetrics(lpdis->hDC, &tm);

            WCHAR symbol[3];
            GetWindowText(lpdis->hwndItem, symbol, 3);

            SIZE textSize;
            GetTextExtentPoint32(lpdis->hDC, symbol, wcslen(symbol), &textSize);

            // Calculate button dimensions
            int buttonWidth = lpdis->rcItem.right - lpdis->rcItem.left;
            int buttonHeight = lpdis->rcItem.bottom - lpdis->rcItem.top;

            // Define the roundness of the rectangle (change this value to adjust the roundness)
            int cornerRadius = 10;

            // Draw the round rectangle button
            HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(59, 59, 59));
            SelectObject(lpdis->hDC, hPen);
            SelectObject(lpdis->hDC, hBrush);
            RoundRect(lpdis->hDC, lpdis->rcItem.left, lpdis->rcItem.top, lpdis->rcItem.right, lpdis->rcItem.bottom, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);

            // Set the background mode and background color for the text
            SetBkMode(lpdis->hDC, TRANSPARENT);
            SetBkColor(lpdis->hDC, RGB(59, 59, 59));

            // Calculate the position to center the text inside the button
            int textX = (buttonWidth - textSize.cx) / 2;
            int textY = (buttonHeight - textSize.cy) / 2;

            // Set the text color to white
            SetTextColor(lpdis->hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));

            // Draw the text inside the button
            DrawText(lpdis->hDC, symbol, -1, &lpdis->rcItem, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

            DeleteObject(hPen);
            DeleteObject(hBrush);
        }

        break;
    }

    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
        SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(32, 32, 32));  // Set the background color (red in this example)
        SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255, 255, 255));  // Set the text color (green in this example)
        return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);  // Return the handle to a null brush to prevent background erasure
    }

    case WM_CHAR:
    {
        int keyCode = (int)wParam;
        std::wstring op = L"+-*/";

        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case VK_BACK:
            if(input.length() > 0)
        {
            input = input.substr(0, input.length() - 1);
            SetWindowText(inputBox, input.c_str());
        }
            break;

        case 0x0D:
            answer = double2wstr(CalculateInput(input));
            input = L"0";
            break;

        default:
            for (int k = 0; k < op.size(); k++)
            {
                if (wParam == op[k]) input += op[k];
            }

            if (keyCode >= 0x30 && keyCode <= 0x39) /* ranges 0...9 */
            {
                input += (wchar_t)keyCode;
            }

            break;
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_SIZE:
    {

        /* Uncomment if you want when user resize window ratio will use
        {
            RECT size{};
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &size);

            int width = min(size.right - size.left, size.bottom - size.top), height = width * WINDOW_RATIO;
            SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
        }
        */

        {
            RECT size{};
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &size);

            int width = size.right - size.left, height = size.bottom - size.top;
            Vector2i boardPos = BOARD_POS(height);
            const int spacing = BUTTON_SPACING;
            Vector2i buttonSize = Vector2i(width / BOARD_COLUMNS - spacing, (height - boardPos.y) / BOARD_ROWS - spacing);

            HWND targetButton = buttons[0 * BOARD_COLUMNS + 0];

            RECT button;
            GetClientRect(targetButton, &button);

            // Calculate the new font size based on the window size
            int newFontSize = ((button.right - button.left) + (button.bottom - button.top)) / 4;

            // Create a new font with the updated size
            HFONT hFont = DEFAULT_FONT(newFontSize);

            for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_COLUMNS; col++)
                {
                    HWND hButton = buttons[row * BOARD_COLUMNS + col]; // Get the button handle from the stored vector

                    SetWindowPos(
                        hButton,
                        NULL,
                        (spacing + (buttonSize.x + spacing) * col) + boardPos.x,
                        (spacing + (buttonSize.y + spacing) * row) + boardPos.y,
                        buttonSize.x,
                        buttonSize.y,
                        SWP_NOZORDER);
                    // Set the new font for the button
                    SendMessage(hButton, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(hFont), TRUE);

                    // Invalidate the button to trigger a repaint
                    InvalidateRect(hButton, nullptr, TRUE);
                }
            }

            SetWindowPos(inputBox, NULL, 0, 0, width, boardPos.y - 0, SWP_NOZORDER);
            // Set the new font for the button
            SendMessage(inputBox, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(hFont), TRUE);

            // Invalidate the button to trigger a repaint
            InvalidateRect(inputBox, nullptr, TRUE);
        }

        break;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        // Handle button press
        int buttonID = LOWORD(wParam);

        // special button char
        std::vector<std::wstring> special = { L"\uE94D", L"CE", L"C", L"\uE94F", L"\uE94E" };
        std::vector<std::wstring> op = { L"\uE948", L"\uE949", L"\uE947", L"\uE94A" };

        // Check if the button ID corresponds to one of our buttons
        if (buttonID >= 1 && buttonID <= buttons.size())
        {
            int buttonIndex = buttonID - 1;
            HWND hButton = buttons[buttonIndex];

            WCHAR temp[3];
            GetWindowText(hButton, temp, 3);

            if (!Filter(special, temp))
            {
                if (input.size() != 0 && input[0] == L'0') input.erase(0, 1);
                input += TranslateUnicode(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                if (wcscmp(temp, special[0].c_str()) == 0)
                {
                    NegateNumber(input);
                }
                else if (wcscmp(temp, special[1].c_str()) == 0)
                {
                    EraseFinalNumber(input);
                }
                else if (wcscmp(temp, special[2].c_str()) == 0)
                {
                    input.clear();
                }
                else if (wcscmp(temp, special[3].c_str()) == 0)
                {
                    if (!input.empty()) input.pop_back();
                }
                else if (wcscmp(temp, special[4].c_str()) == 0)
                {
                    answer = double2wstr(CalculateInput(input));
                    input = answer;
                }

                
            }


            SetFocus(hWnd);
        }

        break;
    }

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
    {
        if (input != prevInput)
        {
            if (answer.empty())
            {
                SetWindowTextW(inputBox, input.c_str());
                prevInput = input;
            }
            else
            {
                SetWindowTextW(inputBox, (prevInput + L"=" + answer).c_str());
                prevInput = input;
            }

            answer.clear();
        }

        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
// ...
```

this is not my full code. My full code is here:

https://github.com/Octopus-Computer/W32Calc/blob/master/Source/Main.cpp

Can you help me, please?

im try to make static empty use `SetWindowText(inputBox, L"");` to make them empty but text doesnt change.

Comment: Lots of issues with this code. I haven't looked closely, but you're deleting objects while they are still selected into a device context and leaking fonts on every resize. Those issues are guaranteed to catch up with you. It's a good idea to get a good grip on the basics before moving on to more advanced things like custom rendering of controls.

Comment: FYI: I would recommend to explicitly use wide character functions, like `SendMessageW` and `SetWindowTextW` whenever possible. When using the macros, you unintentionally mix both wide char and ansi which produces compile errors on other machines. For example during analysis I tried to compile your code but had a ton of errors because ansi was set by default.

Comment: So if you don't support both ansi and UTF-16 you should be explicit with your functions!

Comment: Specify `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` in the `CreateWindowEx()` of your main window and change the return value for `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` to a solid color brush of your desired background color. Currently you specified `NULL_BRUSH`, so already drawn text does not get overwritten by the background color. This is the "ghoasting" effect.

Comment: I have no problem with the code when inputing and pressing backspace. Tell me how to reproduce it. But I get ghost text when resizing.https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5QfT.png That gives me an idea. Maybe you should redraw or update the window after the code you have problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your underlying problem is the `GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH)` in `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`. When you delete the last character of a text string, the text control needs to undo the drawing of the character. This is usually accomplished by erasing with a background color. Since you specified to use no background color *(NULL_BRUSH)* you have this ghoasting effect.

To fix the issue you should change `GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH)` to a solid color brush that represents your background color. Furthermore it is generally recommended to specify `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` in `CreateWindowEx` of the parent, so that each child control has the responsibility to paint itself.

Comment: @IInspectable I guess my previous anwer was to focussed on a dirty fix without `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`. This should be better advice. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fixes your problem. But: For virtual-key codes like `VK_BACK`, you need to process the `WM_KEYDOWN` message, not `WM_CHAR`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown

Comment: i change WM_CHAR to WM_KEYDOWN it doesnt work. I mean ghost text when press backspace it become ghost text not key doesnt process. But when i use WM_CHAR some key use press shift with some key will work because WM_CHAR process character input, but WM_KEYDOWN doesnt proceed key with shift

Comment: @PhamDucDuy The WM_CHAR is fine